# Closed path complex integral with non anaytic function gives me zero

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

When i calculate

$$\oint_C \left(\overline z\right)^2 \mathbb dz$$

Along $|z|=1$, it gives me $0$.

Then i remembered with Cauchy's Theorem,

" If we have an analytic function and want to integrate it along closed path, then we have $0$ as the result".

Then i tried to check the analiticity with Cauchy-Riemann Equation, and it's not satisfied.

Well, randomly i change the radius to $123$, and it still gives me $0$

Could i conclude

$$\oint_C (\overline z)^2 \mathbb dz$$

Is always $0$, when it's evaluated along $|z|=R$ ? Where $R$ is any radius?

NB : But it fails to be $0$ when around the  $|z-1|=1$

But why?

What is the best reason?

Comment: Just because analytic functions yield 0, it doesn't mean that non-analytic functions can not yield zero. They generally don't, but special cases might still do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EDIT: this answer is wrong because the part derivative term in the integral is not conjugated.

Since the curve is symmetric about the real axis, the integral is equivalent to $\int_C z^2 dz$. Thus by Cauchy's theorem, it is zero.

Comment: Even if $\overline{z}^2$ is not analytic?

Comment: But it's just hold on $|z|=R$ (maybe). Then it failed when i tried $|z-1|=R$.???

Comment: @user516076 Did the integral fail to be zero for the contour $|z-1| = 1$, say?

Comment: @user516076 the contour $|z-1| = R$ is symmetric about the real line.

Comment: Actually $$\oint_C\overline{z}^2 \mathbb dz$$ along $|z-1|=1$ gives me $4\pi i$. And it's symmetric to the real axis.

Comment: It is untrue that $z^2=e^{i2\theta}$ is equal to $(\bar z)^2=e^{-i2\theta}$ on $|z|=1$.  Rather, $(\bar z)^2=\frac1{z^2}$ on $|z|=1$.

Comment: If this argument worked, it should also work for $\overline{z}^1$, shouldn't it?

Comment: @DanielFischer exactly. It is wrong because the derivative of the contour doesn’t get conjugated.

Answer (score 7):

Note that on $|z|=1$, $\bar z=\frac1z$.  Hence, we have

$$\oint_{|z|=1}(\bar z)^2\,dz=\oint_{|z|=1}\frac1{z^2}\,dz$$

Inasmuch as the residue of $\frac1{z^2}$ is $0$, we conclude that

$$\oint_{|z|=1}(\bar z)^2\,dz=0$$

And we are done.

Comment: Actually when i type $\overline{z}$, it's not the reciprocal of $z$. But it's a conjugate. I'm sorry if my notation is wrong. Bcz when i substitute $z=x+iy$, $\frac{1}{z}$ and $\overline z$ is not same.?

Comment: When $|z|=1$, $z=e^{i\phi}$ and $\bar z=e^{-i\phi}$.  Hence, for $|z|=1$ we do indeed have $\bar z=\frac1z$.

Comment: @MarkViola you are correct. The other answer will be deleted as soon as I’m at a computer.

Comment: @MarkViola isnt the substitution reversing the orientation of the curve

Comment: @Upstart There is no substitution.  It is an equality.

Comment: @user516076 The accepted answer is not correct as indicated in the "EDIT."  Just curious ... Would you care to change this?